# How to retrieve Custom Field values in Workfront via Python?

Tags: python-3.x, workfront-api

How do you read custom field values that are returned to a variable?  In the example belpw, if I had a custom field in a project called "Custom Field"  I understand I can search and return it by saying:

```
results = client.search(ObjCode.PROJECT,{'groupID':user.homeGroupID},fields=['DE:Custom Field'])
```

How would I the  read the value of the custom field that has spaces in the name?
similar to:

```
print(results.status)
```

How would you do something similar for a custom field like:

```
print('results.CustomField')
```

Comment: I've played with this for about an hour and couldn't get it. The python module for Workfront seems to be made to be pretty cumbersome and it has not been updated in years. It is built upon api version 4.0 and we are currently on version 9.0.

Comment: Brian, here is a Workfront API module I wrote. We use this internally here. It is setup for Python 3. The documentation isn't great, but the code is well commented if you want to see how it works. You can also check out some of the end to end tests for what is effectively code samples. A bit more info here in the repo as well https://github.com/craiglathrop218/workfrontapi_plus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the call runs successfully, the value of `results` should now be a JSON object. That JSON object should have several default fields such as `ID` and possibly `name`, but it will also have a field named `DE:Custom Field` and the value. For example:

`{'ID':'ABC123F2010314AFE1...',
'DE:Custom Field': 'This is the value of my custom field'}`

So in python you would get the value using square bracket notation (assuming you have converted from JSON to a python object). In this case

`print(results['DE:Custom Field'])`

Comment: Tried that method and got the error
TypeError: 'Issue' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Ahh, you are using the default Workfront API module. I don't recall how to use that but I think you will need something like results.data['DE:Custom Field']. Here is an alternative API that I wrote a while back https://pypi.org/project/workfrontapi-plus/. The problem is that the default API has this kinda odd CRUD wrapper around it.

Comment: Craig, thanks for the help.  How would you do that in the workfrontapi-plus?  what would be the syntax?